# How to add words to a text file in Processing?

Tags: processing

I have a Processing code which displays words from a text file. I have created a right click function which erases words from the screen if they are not wanted, so that next time the code is run, those words should not be seen. I created another file containing all the delimiters/words that are not required. How do I add the unwanted words to this file, on the right click? I hope my question is clear. Thanks a lot for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start the application, I imagine you also load the delimiters/unwanted words text file and add those to a String[]. When there's another right click, you append that right clicked word to the loaded String[] of unwanted words and then decide when you want to save the file(overwrite the previous definitions) - with a save button, using a timer, etc.

Here's a quick snippet to illustrate the idea:

```
String[] unwantedWords;//array of words to be loaded from an external text file

void loadUnwantedWords(){
  unwantedWords = loadStrings("unwanted.txt");//load words from text file 
}
void saveUnwantedWords(){
  saveStrings("unwanted.txt",unwantedWords);//save words to text file
}
void addUnwantedWord(String word){//call this on your right click event
  unwantedWords = append(unwantedWords,word);//append a new value to the existing unwanted words array
}
```

Note that normally and Array has a fixed size, but Processing's [append()](http://processing.org/reference/append_.html) function allows you to add new values to an existing array. Once you're array is updated, all you need to do is save it back to the text file, so the new definitions will be there when you restart the application

Comment: Thanks, that is of great help. I am confused as to how can I call the function on right click, as in how do I call addUnwantedWord() on right click for it to do the required task? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Oh, I assumed you had the right clicking in place already for some reason. That's a good question (could go in another post), because it's easy to check for right clicks, but I can't figure out at the moment how to determine what text is displayed under the mouse.